# How to run multiple logstash on same host

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I want to run multiple logstash on same host but i dont know how make configure.

Who is step by step tell me for make configure ?

Thank you for interest.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell logstash where to get the config file on the command line:

```
bin/logstash -f config1.conf
```

Start a second one with a different config file:

```
bin/logstash -f config2.conf
```

If you want to do this from startup, you would need to configure separate initd/systemd for each desired process.

Can you explain what your use case is?  Logstash can handle multiple inputs and some pretty complex configurations with just one process.